# How can I set a default field to a complex form while maintaining ability to add new fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I currently have the ability to create a new "Form", and dynamically add more "Questions" to that form and more "Skills" to each question. My current setup is that a question can either be a free response question or a statically answered question (string or integer), each question's "type" is toggled by a boolean. I'd like to be able to have 1 default entry for a free response question and keep the ability to dynamically add static questions. I haven't been able to come up with the appropriate solution for this, and I can't seem to find anything regarding this on Stack Overflow already. For context:

## Form Model

```
class Form < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :classrooms

  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:label].blank? }

  has_many :responses, dependent: :destroy
end
```

## Question Model

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :form, optional: true

  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy

  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills, inverse_of: :question
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:label].blank? }
end
```

## Skill Model

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions
end
```

## Main Form Layout

```
<%= form_for [@classroom, @form] do |f| %>
  <% if @form.errors.any? %>
    <div class="card">

      <h4><%= pluralize(@forest.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this forest from being saved:</h4>

      <ul>
        <% @form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>

    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field six columns offset-by-three columns">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => "label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :style => "width: 100%", autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>

    <%= render 'question_fields', :f => builder %>

  <% end %>

  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Question", f, :questions %></p>

  <div class="actions six columns offset-by-three columns">
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, you can actually set properties of an object while in the `new` action. Since I was already building the objects in the `new` action as necessary for a complex form, I figured I'd simply check when I was on the final build (since I was saying `3.times { doing stuff here }` ), and change that particular instance's `free` property to `true` and its `static` proprty to `false`.

This would allow me to check if an instance of the form builder had the `free` property set to true at any time. If it was, I could then render HTML with `fields_for` that specific instance, else I could render the default HTML `fields_for`. 
Original and modified code for contrast below, with changes being pointed to:

## Original [NEW] action

```
def new
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:classroom_id])
    @form = @classroom.forms.new

    3.times do
      question = @form.questions.build
      4.times { question.skills.build }
      question = @form.questions.build
      question.free = true
      question.static = false
    end
 end
```

## Modified [NEW] action

```
def new
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:classroom_id])
    @form = @classroom.forms.new
    3.times do |n|
      unless n == 2 <------ Unless this is the final object being built...
        question = @form.questions.build
        4.times { question.skills.build }
      else <----- The final object is being built, so let's change its proprties...
        question = @form.questions.build
        question.free = true
        question.static = false
      end
    end
 end
```

## Nested form template rendered in "Main Form Layout" from question in orignal post

```
<div class="form-fields six columns offset-by-three columns">

  <% unless f.object.try(:free?) %> <--- Unless this instance of question has the `free` attribute set to true
    <div class="header">
      <span>Question Static</span>
      <p><%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %></p>
      <p><%= f.object.free %></p>
    </div>

    <%= f.label :label, :class => "label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :label, :style => "width: 75%", autofocus: true %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :static, :value => true %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :free, :value => false %>

    <%= f.fields_for :skills do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'skill_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>

    <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Skill", f, :skills %></p>
  <% else %> <--- This instance of question has proprty `free` set to true, so let's render the appropriate HTML for it
    <%= render 'question_free_fields', :f => f %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Hope this helps anyone!